# importing any component from react-bootstrap throws error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-bootstrap

I have some weird error everytime when I'm trying to use some component from 'react-bootstrap'. Here is some small example where I'm importing "HelpBlock" component.

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import HelpBlock from 'react-bootstrap';

class RegisterFormDetails extends React.Component {

...
              <HelpBlock>{validationErrorMessage}</HelpBlock>
            }
          </div>
        </div>
    );
      };
export default RegisterFormDetails;
```

but then I'm getting this error

```
Attempted import error: 'react-bootstrap' does not contain a default export (imported as 'HelpBlock').
```

my package.json

```
    {
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.3",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
    "react-bootstrap-sweetalert": "^4.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.3",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.5",
    "react-select": "^2.4.1"
  }
}
```

somebody can help me ? I have rechecked the react-bootstrap folder in node_modules and contains the component which I'm trying to import

Comment: try this import { HelpBlock } from 'react-bootstrap'; and check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kge48i !

Comment: thanks. I'm so stupid

Answer (score 1):

You can import individual components like:

`import HelpBlock from 'react-bootstrap/HelpBlock ';`

The first one is importing component directly, The above is a default import. Default imports are exported with export default .... There can be only a single default export. Since  'react-bootstrap' does not contain a default export , you have to import directly.

or `import { HelpBlock } from 'react-bootstrap';`

Here, only HelpBlock will be imported. Hope it helps.

This [article](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-es6-modules/) will help you to understand es6 modules.